# Does Tomcat 7.0 close DataSource when reloading an application?

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource

I'm trying to know if I reload the project the datasource will be closed or not?
So I extend the `BasicDataSource.class`, override the `close()` and write some log message in the method.

But when I reload (from Tomcat Web Application Manager) the project I don't see the log.

So it means that the tomcat datasource will not close when the project reload?

Comment: How do you initialize Datasource? Just on code or on tomcat?

Comment: I follow this article to custom datasource

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories

Comment: I think (but do not have source) that tomcat does not reload datasource unless whole server is restarted. Once I tried to change parameter of db pool trough JMX unsuccesfully. Dunno what happens if webapp is undeployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

There are two kind of Datasources,

- context-only datasources placed in the project's `META-INF`.
- Over-all datasources placed inside of the `conf/context.xml`

Inside of the `conf/context.xml`:

```
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
```

Tomcat hold it available while tomcat lives, at least for the ROOT-Application if you have one.

But i dont know if the datasource is closed when all applications are down.

Comment: Um, take care about project's `context.xml`, if tomcat is allowed to do: he copies the `context.xml` into `tomcat/conf/Catalina/<hostname>/<project'sname>.xml` so you can insert live-data-configurations in there.